# oracle query need to compare and get result in the same query

Tags: oracle, comparison, fetch

I have a query which fetch record from one db and insert it into another db across servers using script.

the query is like :-

```
select id, date, iscomplete 
from sourcedb.test where id = '1' 
and date = '2011-03-15' and iscomplete = 1;
```

this query returns me some records, which i want only when there are certain number of records.
for ex:- there are 10 records for '2011-03-15' then I want to fetch those 10 records only when is complete is 1 for all the 10 records.

I dont want to hardcode it as records can increase in near future from 10 to 20.

Is there any way I can modify my original query and check if iscomplete = 1 for all the records for that day then fetch the records else return nothing.

I need to add one more condition to this query that is if there are 10 records and half of them are completed i.e. isComplete = 1 and half of them are isComplete <> 1 in this case I dont want any output from the query untill and unless all the record has isComplete = 1.

Regards,
Manasi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the next check

```
select id, date, iscomplete  
  from sourcedb.test 
 where id = '1'  
   and date = '2011-03-15'  
   and not exists (select 1 from sourcedb.test where id = '1' 
                   and date = '2011-03-15' and isComplete <> 1);
```

Comment: solves my problem...thanks.....is there any alternative for using subquery as it will not be optimized....right?